# Comparing dates of type String in Java minus few days

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I was trying to compare two dates which are of type String(After applying SimpleDateFormat) now i have a to apply logic like to check the date which i am receiving is 7 days less the today's date.

The format of both the dates are yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: If you are creating the string form of the dates anyway, why not just compare the original date objects?

Comment: You don't have to beg for help here. Can you provide something you tried or some details like code.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-datetime-in-minutes/12852021#12852021) for an example of calculating the difference between dates and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559772/string-to-joda-localdate-in-format-of-dd-mmm-yy/17560962#17560962) for converting a String to a DateTime object all using JodaTime ;)

Comment: Do you want it exactly 7 days less or within 7 days?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - exactly less then seven days

Comment: This question needs editing for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DateExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isWithin("2014-01-01", -7));
        System.out.println(isWithin("2014-01-03", -7));
        System.out.println(isWithin("2013-12-27", -7));
    }

    public static boolean isWithin(String date, int days){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateProvided = null;
        try {
            dateProvided = format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Date comparisonDate = calendar.getTime();

        return comparisonDate.equals(dateProvided);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i need to calculate with in 7 days?

Answer (score 3):

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library makes this kind of date-time calculation much easier. Avoid using the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

In this case, Joda-Time offers a handy `minusDays()` method along with comparison methods `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

### Parsing

That string format happens to be standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Joda-Time conveniently takes such standard strings as arguments to the constructors of its date-time instances. So no need to define a formatter.

If using other non-standard formats, Joda-Time has a variety of ways to specify a format to use in parsing the string. Search on "joda format" for many examples here in StackOverflow.com.

### Time Of Day

If you truly care about date only without any time-of-day, use the [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class. If you are concerned with time, such as caring about when day starts in certain time zones, then use [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class and call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) method.

### Example Code

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

String string = "2011-02-03";
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( string );
LocalDate sevenDaysAgo = LocalDate.now().minusDays( 7 );
boolean isThatDateMoreThanSevenDaysAgo = localDate.isBefore( sevenDaysAgo );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
System.out.println( "sevenDaysAgo: " + sevenDaysAgo );
System.out.println( "isThatDateMoreThanSevenDaysAgo: " + isThatDateMoreThanSevenDaysAgo );
```

When run…

```
localDate: 2011-02-03
sevenDaysAgo: 2013-12-26
isThatDateMoreThanSevenDaysAgo: true
```

## Java 8

In Java 8 you may either continue to use Joda-Time or switch to the new bundled [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Those new classes were inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the comparisation on the dates before doing any conversion to strings.

Checkout the many questions [already posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309558/time-comparison).

Comment: the date which iam receving is not having anytime stamp, i need to convert system date to the format which i receing in that process it is converting into String

Comment: Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: But while comparing sys date, it will be having some time stamp, Like some value, so while comapring it will be false?

Answer (score 1):

Working with j.u.Date is ugly because you are interested in just the plain date, but this class is a kind of global timestamp. At the moment I would recommend [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)-class `org.joda.time.LocalDate` for this task.