# convert string to datetime and compare for the 2 date diff

Tags: eclipse

Question 1: I have 2 fields to let user enter start date and end date, but in string format
- DateStart (string: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm)
- DateEnd (string: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm)

May I how to compare both datetime? I want to know total how many hours is difference between the both date.

Question 2: user will enter 1 returnDate (string: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm) also in string format, may I know how to update the returnDate if I will need to add 55hours on the returnDate?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with DateTime's functions of Java?

Comment: For Q1; step 1, parse, step 2 compare, step 3 profit

Comment: What time zone? The difference in hours depends on the time zone because of Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies.

Comment: You are asking 3 questions rather than one: (1) How to parse a string into a date-time object in Java, (2) How to calculate the number of hours between two date-time values (an interval), and (3) How to add hours to a date-time. All of these questions have been asked and answered on StackOverflow many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19658291/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3581258/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which will allow you to convert the `String` value to a `Date` object.

For example...

```
try {
    // Note hh is Hour in am/pm (1-12), based on you example, it's not possible
    // now the day part (ie am or pm), you could supply aa as the am/pm marker
    // or use HH which is Hour in day (0-23)
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm");
    Date date = sdf.parse("2014/04/11 4:46");
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to calculate the difference between the two dates, see [How to find difference between two Joda-Time DateTimes in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021#12852021) for an example

It should be noted that you could skip the use of `SimpleDateFormat` and JodaTime all the way, check out [String to joda LocalDate in format of "dd-MMM-yy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559772/string-to-joda-localdate-in-format-of-dd-mmm-yy/17560962#17560962) for an example of converting a `String` to a `LocalDate` using JodaTime

To add time to an existing `Date`, you can use either [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or JodaTime, see [how to add days to java simple date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842934/how-to-add-days-to-java-simple-date-format/21842959#21842959) for an example of both

I would recommend that if you are using some kind of GUI, you might consider using one of the available date pickers as it will save you a lot of hassel

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, I now able to convert from string to datetime.. can you guide me on how to compare the 2 date diff and also how if I need to add 55hours on the returnDate?

Comment: Yep, check all the things...1 calculates the difference in time between two dates, one adds time to date...

Comment: Should be "check all the links" ... :P

Comment: And check the links in my comment on the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Java8's `java.util.time` package

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String dateString1 = "2014/04/10 00:00";
    String dateString2 = "2014/04/11 23:59";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString1, dtf);
    LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString2, dtf);


    // do your stuff with the dates...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
        String date1 = "2014/04/10 15:30";
    String date2 = "2014/04/11 09:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

    try {
        Date parsedDate1 = sdf.parse(date1);
        Date parsedDate2 = sdf.parse(date2);
        double secs = (parsedDate2.getTime() - parsedDate1.getTime()) / 1000;
        double hours = secs / 3600;

        System.out.println(hours);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For adding hours to a date:

```
Date date = new Date(someDateObject.getTime() + 55 * 3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: What if the date itself is different ie yesterday and tomorrow?  Your diff calculation would be wrong...

Comment: you can change the date as you like but if date2 is before date1 you will receive a negative value.String date1 = "2014/04/02 15:30"; 
  String date2 = "2013/04/02 14:30"; will return -8761.0

Comment: What happens when you want to know if it's been x number of days, but in hours, like 48 hours, for example...